# Wordpress on Ubuntu install plugins without FTP access

Tags: wordpress, ftp, wordpress-hook

I run my own web server for development and, on it, I installed a WordPress instance. When I try to add plugins to this instance from the admin interface, WordPress asks for FTP access.

I don't use FTP and have no plans to do so in the future. I know I can change some configuration in WordPress so that I am able to upload without FTP. What exactly should I configure to accomplish this?

Comment: Did I not answer your question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One of three things:

1. Either change permissions so your web server can read the wp-content directory, which should be fine for a development server.
2. Run PHP as FastCGI which can run as a different user than your web server.
3. Install the ssh extension for PHP (`sudo apt-get install libssh2-php` on ubuntu on think)

Comment: +1 - Just dealt with this issue myself. I used solution #1 and `chown`'d the directory containing wordpress to user `www-data`.

Comment: @Ryan for you own sake and sanity, it might be better to use setfacl to give you and www-data access to it, just so you can access the files as well.

Comment: You just blew my mind. I never knew `setfacl` existed, but it will undoubtedly make my life easier. Thanks!

Comment: Curiously, changing group ownership to www-data with rw perms still resulted in the ftp page being invoked. Only when changing the actually owner to www-data did it go away. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 14):

Execute this command on your ubuntu terminal

```
sudo chown -R www-data /var/www
```

Comment: Shouldn't just the group www-data be enough?

Comment: I think, assigning the group as www-data would be enough, no need for www-data as the user

Answer (score 1):

DON FLANNAGAN’s method works for me , THX

> Blockquote

One way to do it is change assign ownership of the wordpress installation to www-data:

chown -R www-data:www-data .
Change file permissions:

chmod -R g+rwX .
Add yourself to the www-data group:

usermod -a -G www-data myusername

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

I was not satisfied with any of these answers so I kept on searching. I found an answer that was so simple I was surprised it had not been mentioned already.

https://askubuntu.com/a/826805/145472

This answer says to add a line to wp-config.php

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

Job done. I cannot take credit for knowing this but I do feel it needs a mention here too.

Comment: Yes, it's correct but see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59497181/889126

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is change assign ownership of the wordpress installation to www-data:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data .
```

Change file permissions:

```
chmod -R g+rwX .
```

Add yourself to the www-data group:

```
usermod -a -G www-data myusername
```

Answer (score -1):

The funny thing is that uploading media works. So I was wondering why plugins not? After changing the ownership of wp-admin it worked for me.

```
sudo chown -R www-data wp-admin
```