# How do I know which linux user Wordpress uses for plugin installation

Tags: wordpress, nginx, centos, vps, centos6

I'm trying to setup Wordpress to be able to install plugins via SFTP (SSH) on a Centos 6 VPS.

I've been able to modify `wp-config` so it uses the right credentials with `user` as my SFTP user.

Now I have a permission related problem, as if I do a `chmod 777` on my `wp-content` folder I'm able to install, but with the normal permissions it can't create folders.

I'm using Nginx and all my `wp-content` files and folders are owned by `user` and I've tried setting the group to `nginx` but it doesn't work.

I also tried setting the user as `nginx` but still no luck.

UPDATE : I found out wordpress was using `apache` as user but I want to change this to my `user` instead. How can I do this ?

Comment: What is the output of ls -la for your plugins folder?

Comment: Everyting is owned by `user` with `nginx` group and rights `drwxr-xr-x`. But I've noticed one of the folder, the one for the plugin install I tried without `chmod 777` is set to `apache`. So I guess the user is `apache` then but this is not going to work. How can I change it ?

Comment: nginx , php-fpm , user and group and also file and folder permissions are answered in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32727581/2977976)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

On your production server, in your WordPress index.php file, at the top, you can temporarily put `echo(exec("whoami"));die();`

Then browse to your WordPress site and see what user was running.  On Ubuntu, mine was `www-data`.

This was useful for me for: [Can I install/update WordPress plugins without providing FTP access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640409/can-i-install-update-wordpress-plugins-without-providing-ftp-access)

Comment: Same here. The user for apache on Debian was "www-data".

Comment: Dont know the reason but on browser exec function was returning null, had to execute the index.php file from cli then it returned the username.

Answer (score 3):

The Wordpress user is also the web server user, so this should work:

> ps -ef | grep http

or

> ps -ef | grep apache

Answer (score 1):

So it clearly says that a group has no W access.

You can do: chmod -R g+w /your/plugins/dir

And then, nginx group will be able to write there.

Comment: My bad I didn't even see this but it still won't create the folder.

Comment: Yes, also I've tried `chown -R apache` on my folder and now it works but I'd rather not have wordpress use `apache` but my `user` instead. How can I do this ? I'll update the question

Comment: You didn't said you have an apache there.. well. I think you can't, may a more experience linux user correct me. Also, worth trying to change nginx/apache configuration to run under your username, but then im not sure if it will not screw things up for the rest of the mechanism... but try it.

Comment: I don't. `apache` is probably the default username for Wordpress and that's why I want to change it. Although I guess it's better to let the web server run as its own user for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's not about /wp-content file permissions, so just leave the WordPress directory directory /wp-content permissions as 0755.

The fix that is required here has to be initiated within apache2.conf file; there we need to change "AllowOverride" directive for our /www/html/ directory from "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All"

Follow the complete procedure here [How to deal with GCP WordPress error "This page isn’t working example.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52251640/how-to-deal-with-gcp-wordpress-error-this-page-isn-t-working-example-com-is-cur)

With this we tell a web server to allow a use of .htaccess file.