# Wordpress Plugin Installation - Failed to connect to FTP Server - Safest Solution?

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, nginx, ftp

I succesfully set up a VPS LEMP-stack with Wordpress. When I am trying to install plugins from the WP backend, I am prompted with the following message:

```
To perform the requested action, WordPress needs to access your web server. 
Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed. If you do not remember your 
credentials, you should contact your web host.
```

When I enter my SFTP-account details, which I am using to access the server with FileZilla, I get the following error message:

```
Failed to connect to FTP Server 192.XXX.XXX.X:21
```

I read [various](http://vps2.me/wordpress-vps-ftp-connection-problem/) [tutorials](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-configure-vsftpd-to-use-ssl-tls-on-an-ubuntu-vps), which suggest to install a FTP server, in particular [vsftpd](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd.html) and then to store your FTP-User-details in the wp-config.php to avoid further authentication requestst. The problem I see is that, FTP is considered as [severly unsecure](http://blog.jdpfu.com/2011/07/10/why-you-need-to-stop-using-ftp) and I would like to avoid hard-coding my user details into my WP-installation.

What is the safest, recommended way to deal with this problem?

Comment: You wouldn't get the FTP message if you had write permissions set on your plugins folders in wp-content

Comment: @JefferyAWooden The following seems to solve my issue: `sudo adduser <username> www-data
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R g+rw /var/www`

Comment: @user3046831 Thanks your post solved my same problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I install/update WordPress plugins without providing FTP access?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640409/can-i-install-update-wordpress-plugins-without-providing-ftp-access)

Answer (score 73):

I don't know if it is the safest method or not. But pasting this code in wp-config.php once solved my problem:

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

Comment: This method fixed the issue for me. However I also had to change the permissions of my themes folder so it could then create the required directories.

Comment: OP didn't pick it as correct answer. Wishes do not come true in this life T_T

Comment: This is effective, but it comes with security problems. This is mentioned briefly in [the documentation at codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_Upgrade_Constants), but unfortunately dumps you on another StackExchange site for [a detailed answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189554/what-security-concerns-should-i-have-when-setting-fs-method-to-direct-in-wp-co)

Comment: According to "all the best" documentation it says to use "define('FS_METHOD', 'ssh2');" but after several hours of debug I found this comment and 'direct' worked for me. And it IS case sensitive.

Answer (score 32):

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data wp_site_root
sudo chmod -R g+rw wp_site_root
```

solved my problem.

Comment: i have a wordpress docker and when clone it need to grant permission by this command ... this is so helpful for us ... thanks

Answer (score 7):

Remember to set files and directories permission in this way:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
find /var/www/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find /var/www/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Comment: For Linux servers only.

Answer (score 5):

`define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');`

adding the above given command on the wp-config file will resolve that issue paste it below

`define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );`

Answer (score 2):

@MrNerdy,

I should have also elaborated on the fact that there should be some other folders you'll want to give permissions to. Read the documentation on it here to understand exactly what you should do regarding security: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Also, be careful to only install trusted plugins. I've seen dozens of sites hacked because of badly coded plugins / themes, etc. Good luck.

Comment: +1 for the headsup to @MrNerdy's comment, which should be added in the answer section.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was bitnami related settings issue. This [**post**](http://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/12/wordpress-plugin-update-failed.html) helped me. There could be multiple reason:

- Permission issue on the files and folders.
- The `FS_METHOD` should be
  "direct" in `wp-config.php` file.
- Remove FTP configuration from `wp-config.php` if you are
  migrating from `bitnami` to manage it on your own.

Answer (score 1):

## If anyone is running into this issue using MAMP Pro.

Make sure you're running the server as the user that has permission for the root wordpress directory.

Under `SETTINGS > Ports` look for "Run server as" and in the drop down choose the same system user that has permission to access the root wp folder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to `wp-config.php`:

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

Then change the permission If you're using an ec2 instance.

```
cd /var/www/html/wordpress
```

Answer (score 1):

its just a permisson error
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data your wordpress site root folder
sudo chmod -R g+rw wordpress site root folder

Answer (score -1):

if your'e using shared hosting then remove some files in your server and try again. it will work. its because your disk quota may be exceeded.