# Wordpress: Failed to connect to ftp server

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I downloaded wordpress to xampp and when l was downloading themes this box popped up. What am l supposed to write for hostname? I wasn't able to find anything online.

Review [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0O0dF.png)

Comment: What is you're OS ? Looks like the user of php (maybe www-data:www-data) isn't allow to write inside `wp-content/[themes|plugins|mu-plugins]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wordpress Plugin Installation - Failed to connect to FTP Server - Safest Solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316282/wordpress-plugin-installation-failed-to-connect-to-ftp-server-safest-solutio)

Comment: I use the latest version of MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

By pasting this code in wp-config.php will solve this problem:

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```