# Installing Wp-Plugin without FTP Access

Tags: wordpress, plugins, ftp, hosting

I have wordpress site on my server which only uses sftp.

I want to install and upgrade plugins, but it appears that you are required to enter your ftp login to install the plugins. Is there a way to install and upgrade plugins by manually uploading the files instead of having wordpress handle the entire process?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I install/update WordPress plugins without providing FTP access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640409/can-i-install-update-wordpress-plugins-without-providing-ftp-access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a plugin by simply uploading to the plugins directory and unpacking it.  '/wp-content/plugins'.    Note that you will still have to enable the plugin normally in Wordpress admin.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

to your wp-config.php
And it will be fine