# How to install a wordpress plugin without providing FTP details?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed wordpress in localhost and now trying to install a jQuery-slider-plugin to it. But when I try to install the plugin, it prompts me to enter the ftp details. Is there any solution to install the wordpress plugins without providing the ftp details?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Just google your _exact_ question title and you'll see this is the top result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640409/can-i-install-update-wordpress-plugins-without-providing-ftp-access

Comment: http://kb.rolet.com/install-wordpress-plugins-without-ftp-access/

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to wp-config

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

For more information visit: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_Upgrade_Constants

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress only asks for FTP details if it cannot modify files on disk. In order to prevent this question one can change the privileges of the files. You can `chown` the files to the user the website is running as.

An alternative method is to define your FTP details in the wordpress configuration; see http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-install-asks-for-ftp-details#post-2455471 for more information.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Lex I do not know whether it is *correct*, but if it is, it is a perfectly good and useful answer.

Answer (score -2):

You can install it by , uploading the plugin and do the settings in the Database , in other way you can install the Wordpress in your local machine  and install every thing then upload it ,

Comment: i dont understand w7y you give me vote = -2 , just I'm trying to helping you . 
BTY thanks .