# How to upload files to folder using WordPress without using FTP or cPanel?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, ftp

I have access to WordPress, but I lost my cPanel and FTP login. I quickly want to move a file to a directory inside wpcontents/plugins/somepluginname/

How can i do this directly via WordPress dashboard? Is it possible?

Comment: may be a plugin like this ( https://wordpress.org/plugins/file-manager ) will help.

Comment: Thanks man. This actually worked! But I wanted to move a 50mb file which became an error.

Comment: here is your question best answers:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640409/can-i-install-update-wordpress-plugins-without-providing-ftp-access