# WordPress : Asking FTP credentials when trying to install a plugin or theme

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp

I'm getting prompted for FTP credentials (ftp username, ftp password, host address) everytime I'm trying to install a plugin or theme in my WordPress Website.

How can I prevent it?

Comment: Check the group and user permissions and owner. On CentOS the group and user should be apache, while on Ubuntu server the user and group should be www-data.

Comment: give permission to the user for that directory, and also check directory permision

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the files are not getting access you are prompted with FTP credentials.

There are 2 options to follow :

1. Provide the FTP credentials inside /wp-config.php file :

> define( 'FTP_USER', 'username' );
>   define( 'FTP_PASS', 'password' );
>   define( 'FTP_HOST', 'ftp.example.com:21' );

2. By Pass the check as show in the SO post :

[Can I install/update WordPress plugins without providing FTP access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640409/can-i-install-update-wordpress-plugins-without-providing-ftp-access#answer-5650020)

Answer (score 7):

Follow the below steps.

1. Open `wp-config.php`
2. Edit the file.
3. Add the following given line after `WP_DEBUG`

   `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');`
4. Save

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to solve this problem is add the following code in your `wp-config.php`

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

If still problem exists, follow the steps given by following link :

https://www.narga.net/stop-fix-wordpress-ask-for-ftp-credentials-upgrade-install-delete-themes-plugins/

Comment: @AnshuPratapYadav, Great , consider to accept my answer and upvote. :)

Comment: @Anshu Pratap Yadav Please see the concerns related to `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');` http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189554/what-security-concerns-should-i-have-when-setting-fs-method-to-direct-in-wp-co