# Adding local user to `www-data` group for WordPress development

Tags: linux, wordpress, nginx

Im developing a WordPress site on a Linux computer and Im running `nginx` with `php-fpm`. By default `nginx` is running from `www-data` user and `www-data` group.

But with this, when I try to install a plugin to WordPress, it asks for FTP details. To overcome this, I simply changed the group of my site folder to `www-data` but in this case I can't edit the files. Files are write protected.

is there any way to add my local user to `www-data` group and overcome this issue without any hacks?

Comment: Basically `adduser <user> <to group>` - buuuut you need to take care first and try other things. Do the fpm workers also run as `www-data` ? You can configure this through `/etc/php5-fpm/pool.d/www.conf` or something like that.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Yes, `php-fpm` works with `www-data` and I didn't want to change it. I just wanted to know the 'right' way of doing this, as in how to do this by adding my user to `www-data` group. I did try `adduser <user> <to group>` but I didn't solve my issue. WordPress still asks for FTP details

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I install/update WordPress plugins without providing FTP access?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640409/can-i-install-update-wordpress-plugins-without-providing-ftp-access)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @jww Thank you very much for pointing out the mistake I have done. Have a nice day.