# How to use sftp instead of ftp when updating wordpress plugins?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, ftp, sftp

Website Information:

**Protocol :** SFTP

**Server :** Google Cloud

**Wordpress Version :** 4.9.8

I am trying to update my WordPress plugins but every time I try to do it, it always asks me for my FTP information but when I supplied my FTP information it returns an error 'Failed to connect to FTP Server.'

I even tried to add Port number '21' and '22' on the hostname but it still doesn't work. I even tried using 'FTPS (SSL)' Connection type but it didn't work either. I've also used the plugin 'SSH SFTP Updater Support' but it leaves my website under maintenance and I can't access it anymore.

I've spent 2 days resolving this problem. Hope that someone can help me with this.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FTP and SFTP are two different protocols. Wordpress offers a facility to upload plugin via FTP. However ***Wordpress does not have SFTP support to install plugins*** as of now, AFAIK. You can go with any of the following routes.

- **Enable Direct Method** Wordpress will be able to install plugins automatically and FTP or SFTP will not be needed. You need to edit wp-config and add following line:

  ```
   define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
  ```

  You can read more on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640409/can-i-install-update-wordpress-plugins-without-providing-ftp-access)
- **Upload plugin zip file via SFTP** You can download plugin and then upload downloaded zip file via your SFTP client e.g FileZilla or you can do it from terminal (on Unix Systems) using `scp`. Reference for installing plugin manually can be found [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Managing_Plugins#Manual_Plugin_Installation_by_Uploading_a_Zip_Archive) and instructions on using `scp` on Linux can be found [here](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php)

Comment: Thank you for this. I will try your suggestions and hope that this will solve my problem :)

Comment: You @OliverPrimo are welcome. Please comment if problem persists.

Comment: Hello @KamranSyed. I tried to add 'define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');' to my wp-config.php and it doesn't require me to supply my FTP info anymore but the problem is that it returns an error 'Update Failed: Could not create directory.' every time I update a plugin.

Regarding the second solution, it is possible to upload a plugin through SFTP but my problem is updating the plugins.

Anyways, Thank you for your response :)

Comment: It has to do with the permissions. Webserver is not able to write on `/wp-content/plugins/`.  Please see this post for permissions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640409/can-i-install-update-wordpress-plugins-without-providing-ftp-access.  I would need to know OS and Webserver installed to provide specific commands. Thanks.

Comment: Okay. Many thanks to you for getting back to me. I'll inform later regarding the information you're asking for. Thank you :)

May I ask, wouldn't it cause vulnerability to the site once I allowed write permission to my wp-content?

Comment: Hello @KamranSyed, I already updated the file permissions of wp-content and wp-content/plugins/ to 777 but it still returns an error: 'Update Failed: Could not create directory.' every time I update a plugin. I'm sorry for being slow but I am a newbie with this. Thank you for your assistance :)

Comment: This vulnerability is inherent in all solutions, allowing webserver to upload files, including Wordpress. `/wp-content/uploads/` is always writable by wordpress (webserver).

Comment: Hello @KamranSyed, I already updated the file permissions of wp-content and wp-content/plugins/ to 777 but it still returns an error: 'Update Failed: Could not create directory.' every time I update a plugin. I'm sorry for being slow but I am a newbie with this. Thank you for your assistance :)

Comment: Permissions 777 will not work as discussed in the stackover post, I mentioned earlier. Please follow the instructions in the post or from Internet to set Wordpress permissions. @OliverPrimo

Comment: Thank you for your response @KamranSyed. I really appreciated your time and effort. I already fixed this with your second solution by downloading the latest plugin and uploading it to the server via Filezilla. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 9):

If only FTP and FTPS (SSL) appear as options on WordPress when installing plugins, etc., then installing the PHP extension for SSH2 will automatically add an SSH2 option (for SFTP) to WordPress.

For example, on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install php-ssh2
```

And restart the web server (e.g. Nginx or Apache).

Comment: Never realised this was even possible, but it works thank you