# How can I Give The Group Permission to WordPress

Tags: wordpress, caddy

I installed WordPress with Caddy server in a Centos server. 
When I was trying to update in dashboard, it required the FTP account.

So I check the authentication of WordPress directory

```
# ls -l
drwxrwxr-x 5 root caddy 4096 wordpress
```

and the user & group of caddy.service

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/caddy.service

...

[Service]
User=caddy
Group=caddy
```

You can see the Group Permission of 'wordpress' is r/w/x.

However, Dashboard still requires FTP information unless I change the owner from root to caddy.

But I prefer caddy to root to be the directory owner.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I install/update WordPress plugins without providing FTP access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640409/can-i-install-update-wordpress-plugins-without-providing-ftp-access)

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in **wp-config.php**. This may help you.

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```