# Is it safe to allow FS_METHOD=direct for Wordpress to update plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to WordPress and have been updating WP website plugin for almost 1 year and today i had 4 plugin to update when it asked me for `To perform the requested action, WordPress needs to access your web server. Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed. If you do not remember your`

after checking i found one solution to update `wp-config.php` and add `define('FS_METHOD','direct');`. This way i am able to update plugins now

Is it safe to add this or what is secure way of updating plugin/

I did same and i was able to update plugin but i am not sure if this is safe or recommended way

Comment: Please check this hope this is helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640409/can-i-install-update-wordpress-plugins-without-providing-ftp-access

Answer (score 0):

`FS_METHOD` set to `direct` in WordPress is safe in certain situations, it's crucial to ensure that your server is configured correctly and file permissions are set appropriately. Using direct file manipulation might be less secure than employing FTP or SSH methods.

In conclusion, although setting `FS_METHOD` set to `direct` can be convenient and effective for many setups, it may not be the safest option in all cases.